# Find fracture in a long loop

Tags: modeling

I have an object which is really long and contains a nice shape of loop. It has a fracture somewhere in it, but I have no idea where(I didn't see it when applying modifiers). I want to find out where the point is where loop is cut so that I can remove that point. Who's got an idea how to do it?

Comment: With `Alt`+`RMB` you select one part of loop; look for any tris / ngons / unexpected vertices where the selection ends.

Comment: Also if the point is that close to another, you may want to try removing doubles (make a copy 1st though, I would sure hate to have you kill your efforts.) To do this: in edit mode select all vertices with `A`, then hit `W` then hit `R`. This suggestion is only meant to help you if you are trying to get rid of the problem. If all you want to do is find it, then I wouldn't go this route.

Comment: Could you upload a Blend file and some screenshots of the issue, it's not clear what you mean by "fractions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the loop cut tool <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to find where an edge loop is broken. When using the loop cut tool, the location of the new edge loop is highlighted on top of your model and you can see faces that the new loop does not go through, to increase clarity you can use the <kbd>[image: MW] Mouse Wheel</kbd> or the numpad <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the number of cuts.

[image: adding a loop cut]